# Trying to run a query using a PHP cURL session and adding for a loop inside PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

There is an AJAX request from a JavaScript file which passes two values to the PHP file.

The PHP file should run the query using a cURL session. The way I tried to work this out is:

```
var queryData={"data":{"data_string":{"data":"oil","default_field":"Content"}}};
var testArgument=0;

$.ajax({
url:"/www/test/php/queryManipulate.php",
type: 'POST',
data: 'dataString',
datatype: 'json',
data: {field : queryData, start : testArgument},
success:function(jsonQuery)
{
    alert(jsonQuery);
}
});
```

Now, what I am trying to do with the PHP file is to add the value of `from` to the query part so that it looks like:

```
{"from": value of testArgument, "data":{"data_string":{"data":"oil","default_field":"Content"}}}
```

And the `testArgument` should have 4 values, 0, 10, 20 and 30, and each value should run the request.

My PHP file looks like :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/testIndex");
$from=$_POST["start"];
$object=json_decode($_POST["field"]); 
$object->from=$_POST["start"]; 
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I'm not sure if I am using cURL the right way. I'm getting the error "Call to undefined function curl_init()."

Comment: Your ajax config object has "data" declared twice. You probably want to delete the line `data: 'dataString',`.

Answer (score 0):

"Call to undefined function curl_init()" means that you do not have the curl extension in your php.

Check [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and you will see that the data you provide is sent using GET. Try the following:

```
$object = json_decode($_GET["field"]);
```

Also it would not work because you at least do not set request target for curl. Curl is a library/utility to query remote servers... what exactly are you trying to get with your curl request?

Comment: I think I ve already provided that.. Please check it above the ajax call..and my php version is 5.3.9

Comment: Ive checked  the php extension php_curl.. its nw showing undefined index

Comment: But where is that url? It should be in the argument of curl_init();

Comment: Your answer is in your question: curl_exec(); You should read curl docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php. There are many examples there.

Comment: I mean is it possible to add a post request inside curl

Comment: `$url = 'http://example.com'; $url .= '?' . $name . '=' . $value;` Or `$url .= '?' . http_build_query($arrayWithqueryParams);`